# Least cost swapping 3

Tags: c++

I've decided to rebuild the code with advices from previous topic [C++ Least cost swapping 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226315/c-least-cost-swapping-2)
I've also decided to change input from passing the file name to passing the content of a file, so i am wondering if the input checking is still correct as in previous version. Please review my code.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

uint32_t constexpr MaxWeight = 6500;
uint32_t constexpr MinVertexes = 2;
uint32_t constexpr MaxVertexes = 1000000;

struct ObjectCollection
{
    size_t count = 0;
    std::vector<uint32_t> weights;
    std::vector<size_t> startingOrder;
    std::vector<size_t> endingOrder;
    uint32_t minWeight = MaxWeight;
};

std::size_t readValue(std::istringstream& iss)
{
    std::size_t value;
    iss >> value;
    if (!iss)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input.");

    return value;
}

std::istringstream readLine(std::istream& stream)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(stream
        , line);
    if (line.empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input");
    return std::istringstream(line);
}

std::vector<size_t> readOrder(std::istringstream iss, size_t const objectCount)
{
    std::vector<size_t> v;
    v.reserve(objectCount);

    int i = 1;
    while (!iss.eof() && i <= objectCount)
    {
        size_t orderNumber = readValue(iss);
        if (orderNumber - 1 > objectCount)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Too high index in order");
        }
        v.push_back(orderNumber - 1);
        ++i;
    }
    if (v.size() != objectCount) throw std::runtime_error("Too few values in line");
    return v;
}

void readWeightsAndSetMinWeight(std::istringstream iss, ObjectCollection& objects)
{
    objects.weights.reserve(objects.count);
    int i = 1;
    while (!iss.eof() && i <= objects.count)
    {
        uint32_t weight = static_cast<uint32_t>(readValue(iss));
        if (weight > MaxWeight)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Too high weight");
        }

        objects.weights.push_back(weight);
        objects.minWeight = std::min(objects.minWeight, weight);
        ++i;
    }
    if (objects.weights.size() != objects.count)
        throw std::runtime_error("Too few values in line");
}


ObjectCollection readFromFile(std::istream& stream)
{
    ObjectCollection objects;

    if (!std::cin.good())
        throw std::exception("Unable to read values");

    readLine(stream) >> objects.count;
    if (objects.count<MinVertexes || objects.count>MaxVertexes)
    {
        throw std::exception("Invalid amount of vertexes");
    }

    readWeightsAndSetMinWeight(readLine(stream), objects);
    objects.startingOrder = readOrder(readLine(stream), objects.count);
    objects.endingOrder = readOrder(readLine(stream), objects.count);

    return objects;
}

uint64_t calculateLowestCostOfWork(ObjectCollection const& objects)
{
    size_t n = objects.count;
    std::vector<size_t> permutation(n);

    //constructing permutation
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        permutation[objects.endingOrder[i]] = objects.startingOrder[i];
    }

    long long result = 0;
    std::vector<bool> visitedVertexes(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (visitedVertexes[i])
            continue;

        size_t cycleSize = 0;
        uint32_t cycleMinWeight = MaxWeight;
        long long cycleSumOfWeights = 0;

        size_t vertexToVisit = i;
        //decomposition for simple cycles and calculating parameters for each cycle
        while (!visitedVertexes[vertexToVisit])
        {
            visitedVertexes[vertexToVisit] = true;
            cycleSize++;
            vertexToVisit = permutation[vertexToVisit];
            cycleSumOfWeights += objects.weights[vertexToVisit];
            cycleMinWeight = std::min(cycleMinWeight, objects.weights[vertexToVisit]);
        }
        //calculating lowest cost for each cycle
        uint64_t swappingWithMinWeightInCycle = cycleSumOfWeights + (static_cast<uint64_t>(cycleSize) - 2) * static_cast<uint64_t>(cycleMinWeight);
        uint64_t swappingWithMinWeight = cycleSumOfWeights + cycleMinWeight + (static_cast<uint64_t>(cycleSize) + 1) * static_cast<uint64_t>(objects.minWeight);
        result += std::min(swappingWithMinWeightInCycle, swappingWithMinWeight);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    ObjectCollection elephants;
    try
    {
        elephants = readFromFile(std::cin);
        std::cout << calculateLowestCostOfWork(elephants);
    }

    catch (std::exception const& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error unknown \n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through the code and see what can be improved.

---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
```

The header names should sorted in alphabetical order.

---

```
uint32_t constexpr MaxWeight = 6500;
uint32_t constexpr MinVertexes = 2;
uint32_t constexpr MaxVertexes = 1000000;
```

`constexpr` is usually put in the beginning because the benefits of east `const` don't really apply to `constexpr` — `constexpr` applies to the entire declaration, just like `static` or `inline` does.  You can't declare a "pointer to `constexpr`" or "reference to `constexpr`" (the pointer / reference itself will be `constexpr` instead).

Add `#include <cstdint>`, and use `std::uint32_t` instead of `uint32_t`.  Also, since you manage to get rid of magic numbers, why not eliminate magic types as well?  Something like

```
using Weight_t = std::uint32_t;
```

---

```
struct ObjectCollection
{
    size_t count = 0;
    std::vector<uint32_t> weights;
    std::vector<size_t> startingOrder;
    std::vector<size_t> endingOrder;
    uint32_t minWeight = MaxWeight;
};
```

Again, `std::size_t` and `std::uint32_t`.  Also, it seems that there is a class invariant that the three vectors are all of size `count`.  You may want to ensure this.

---

```
std::size_t readValue(std::istringstream& iss)
{
    std::size_t value;
    iss >> value;
    if (!iss)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input.");

    return value;
}
```

This is overly restrictive, both in `std::size_t` and `std::istringstream`.  Make it a template:

```
template <typename T, typename Istream>
T read_value(Istream&& is)
{
    T value;
    if (!(is >> value))
        throw std::runtime_error{"invalid input"};
    return value;
}
```

---

```
std::istringstream readLine(std::istream& stream)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(stream
        , line);
    if (line.empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input");
    return std::istringstream(line);
}
```

This function should return a string, not a string stream, in my opinion.  Also, why the line break in the `getline`?

---

```
std::vector<size_t> readOrder(std::istringstream iss, size_t const objectCount)
{
    std::vector<size_t> v;
    v.reserve(objectCount);

    int i = 1;
    while (!iss.eof() && i <= objectCount)
    {
        size_t orderNumber = readValue(iss);
        if (orderNumber - 1 > objectCount)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Too high index in order");
        }
        v.push_back(orderNumber - 1);
        ++i;
    }
    if (v.size() != objectCount) throw std::runtime_error("Too few values in line");
    return v;
}
```

Don't take streams by value.  Take by reference instead.  And it doesn't make very much sense to declare a parameter as top-level `const`.

The while loop should really be a for loop.  Loop counters should start from 0  and use `<` instead of starting from 1 and using `<=`.  Like this:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < objectCount; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

---

The `readWeightsAndSetMinWeight` function is similar.  Casting the result of `readValue` to `uint32_t` doesn't feel right; with the template above, this problem is solved.

---

It seems that you check the input status every time you read something, and throw an exception on failure.  You can automate this by using `istream::exceptions`:

```
std::cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);
```

`std::cin` will automatically throw exceptions of type `std::ios_base::failure` when `failbit` is on.

---

This should be enough to get you started.